# remove My account and Logout links from some phtml pages

Tags: xml, customer-account, phtml, toplinks, logout

i have to remove "My account" & "Log out" links from some phtml pages.
for removing my account, i am using following code :

```
<marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist>
<reference name="top.links">
   <remove name="account_link"/>
</reference>
</marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist>
```

for removing Login and log out , i am using following code :

```
<marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist>
<action method="removeLinkByUrl">
<url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/>
</action>
</marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist>
```

but both are not working

**Update :header.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
/**
 * @var Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header $this
 */
?>
<div class="Manoj">
<div class="Ma">
    <div id="top_head">
      <div class="header_top">
              <div class="header_top_link">               
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_switcher_header') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>  
              </div>
            </div>
            <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>

    </div>
<div id="main_header">
<div class="header-container">
    <div class="header">
    <!--<div class="grid_7 alpha">-->
    <div class="logo">
      <div class="Header_logo">
        <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
        <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
        <?php else:?>
        <h1 class="logo"><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
        <?php endif?>
      </div>

    <!--</div>-->
    <!--<div class="grid_17 omega">-->

      <div class="header_search">
      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
      </div>

      <div class="div_link-cart">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cart_sidebar');?>
            </div>

    <!--</div>-->
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container_menu">
  <div class="inner_menu">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<p id="back-top"><a href="#top" title="<?php echo $this->__('Back to Top') ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Back to Top') ?></a></p>

<style>

ul.solidblockmenu li a {
  border-right: 2px solid #333;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 51px;
  line-height: 38px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 198px !important;
}
</style>
```

**local.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.compare.sidebar</name></action>
    </default>


    <checkout_cart_index> 
        <reference name="header"> 
            <block type="page/header" name="header">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>checkout/cart/cart_header.phtml</template></action> 
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index> 



    <checkout_onepage_index> 
        <reference name="header"> 
            <block type="page/header" name="header">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>checkout/cart/checkout_header.phtml</template></action> 
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_index> 



    <marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist> 
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/></action>
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/></action>

    </marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist>

</layout>
```

Comment: try this <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/></action>
    </reference>

Comment: Logout <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/></action>
    </reference>

Comment: its not working......

Comment: <marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist>
<action method="removeLinkByUrl">
<url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/>
</action>
</marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist>  use that

Comment: <marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist>   <reference name="top.links"> <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/></action> </reference></marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist> use this way

Comment: @QaisarSatti my account is removing, please help me for log out.....

Comment: @Kothari Log out is  not removing....

Comment: <marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist> <action method="removeLinkByUrl"> <url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/> </action> </marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist> try this

Comment: <marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist>  <reference name="top.links"> <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/></action> </reference></marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist> use this in previous is login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this to remove account and logout

```
    <marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist> 
    <reference name="top.links"> 
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/></action>
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/></action>
     </reference>
 </marketplace_marketplaceaccount_myproductslist>
```

Comment: no, still log out is there.....

Comment: Did you remove from top link or some other place

Comment: before i used css to remove top links, now i removed that css. i am using xml to remove log out.....

Comment: updated xml use it and feedback

Comment: sorry, its not working...

Answer (score 1):

To remove Myaccount, Register, Logout url from top links

`e.g,` to remove the links in home page

```
<cms_index_index>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl" /></action>  <!-- My account -->
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl" /></action>   <!-- Log out -->
            <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl" /></action>  <!-- Register -->
        </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

**Note :** Make sure you layout file loaded correctly and make sure your handle is correct.

Comment: my account is removing, please help me for log out.....

Comment: did you add logout through XML or directly added in phtml file?

Comment: i added your code in local.xml file

Comment: i guess "Logout" url is directly hard coded in phtml file

Comment: please let me know what file code you want to check, so that i can post here.....

Comment: header.phtml and local.xml

Comment: please check my updated question

Comment: show your local.xml?

Comment: please check updated question.....